# Apache keep shutting down in front of nginx as reserve proxy (DDOS Attack)

Tags: apache, nginx, ddos

My site/server is under DDOS ATTACK and apache keep shutting down, here is the error-log.

Would someone explain that and if there is a solution to this please advise!

Anyone has any suggestions? Appreciate it!

Server informations:

16/32 CPU cores, 128 GB RAM
Running nginx as reserve proxy in front of apache mpm_worker with php-fpm.

```
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6396 13663/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6397 13663/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1246 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Ta Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/T10 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.15] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Te Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Ta Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/T10 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.15] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Tk Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/To Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.9] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Ti Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Te Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Tw Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.13] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T16 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.18] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Tm Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.8] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/To Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.9] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Ti Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1g Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.23] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1k Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.25] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tq Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.10] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T18 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.19] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1a Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.20] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tw Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.13] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tu Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.12] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Ty Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.14] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T12 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.16] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tk Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tm Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.8] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Ts Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.11] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1o Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.27] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1c Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.21] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1g Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.23] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1e Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.22] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1k Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.25] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1w Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.31] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1i Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.24] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1y Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.32] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1s Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.29] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1q Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.28] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tq Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.10] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T18 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.19] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T1a Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.20] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/Tu Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.12] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T14 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.17] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/Ty Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.14] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T12 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.16] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/Ts Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.11] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T1o Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.27] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T1c Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.21] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6400 13663/T1u Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.30] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1e Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.22] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1w Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.31] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6402 13663/T1u Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.30] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1y Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.32] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1s Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.29] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1q Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.28] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T14 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.17] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6398 13663/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T16 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.18] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/T1m Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.26] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6402 13663/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6399 13663/Tg Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6402 13663/Tg Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6402 13663/T1m Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.26] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6401 13663/T1i Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.24] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6403 13663/T20 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6403 13663/T20 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.6814 15272/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.7127 15289/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.7129 15289/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:49.7892 15289/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 15289
[ N 2022-06-02 20:32:50.0844 13663/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown is most likely due to logs filling up - this is an ancient article but I have a hunch based on your description of the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/627521/why-is-logrotate-causing-apache-to-seg-fault-each-time

Handling DDoS is difficult and resource-intensive.

Maybe not the answer you want to hear, but I strongly recommend using a service like CloudFlare to prevent DDoS - much easier than trying to deal with it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Some steps:

- Create a firewall and open it only to your public IP, you can use `ufw`
- After you confirm you are in a DDoS attack, install this module for apache `mod_evasive`

Some other recommendations are to install a cache in front, like Cloudfare or Cloudfront.